AL8853AQS boost dc-dc converter malfunctioning
I've assembled a boost converter using the AL8853AQ (datasheet). The load is 6 white LEDs, at ~400mA. String voltage is about 34V when cold, dropping to about 31V when hot. The assembly worked without issue for 3-5 hours, being manually cycled on and off every 30 minutes or so. After that time, the string began to flicker, and after a few minutes, went out completely. While flickering, the voltage at the PWM pin was changing rapidly, between 1.5 and 2.5V. I could apply 3.3V to the PWM pin (at the point marked "EN", normally left floating) and force the converter to run. This caused 3-5 mA to flow from the 3.3V source. Within 5 minutes, the string began to flicker again and went out, and could not be forced to run even with 3.3V applied at EN.
I replaced the chip, with the same results.
When it ran, no device on the board was hot. The inductor was warm to the touch. All other parts were indistinguishable by feel from ambient temperature. The LEDs are mounted to two metal core PCBs, both attached to an aluminum heat sink. A thermistor attached to one MCPCB indicated its temperature to be around 60°C. When running, I measured 2.4V at the COMP pin and 1.8V at the OVP pin. When off, I measured 0V at COMP and 0.5V at OVP.
The power supply is rated 12VDC, 4.16A. I have not seen any transients or voltage swings from this power supply in this application. I watched the voltage when connecting the supply, and did not observe any transients.
How am I destroying the controller chip this time?
PC board top layer:

Bottom layer:

Schematic:

R3 is a 1/8Ω 1W resistor.
I couldn't find in my inventory any 63V or higher capacitors for the output, hence the arrangement with C3.1 and C3.2.
In operation, neither cap sees voltage above its rating. I tried a single 4.7uF 100V capacitor, and it made no difference.
C4 is currently not fitted. When it was present, the assembly still didn't work.
Assembly:

Orange wires go to the thermistor.
The LED string is built of two substrings of 3 which are connected in series by the blue/white wires.
Update November 11 2024:
With a 27Ω resistor added to the gate trace, the assembly ran flawlessly for about 25 hours. In order to test my hypothesis, I removed the resistor and placed a jumper in its place, expecting the controller to fail within a few (<5) hours like the previous two. However, it's still running. My best guess is that the design/fabrication of the chip is such that some will fail without gate current limitation, but others will survive.

What's your inductor's saturation current rating? Does the FET survive and only the controller is damaged? Have you replaced the FET too? It doesn't sound like the capacitors are the issue, but series capacitors usually need a balancing resistor across them to ensure voltage sharing.

Every other component survives. Replacing the controller makes the assembly work again. I didn't bother replacing the FET, since that would probably fail shorted, which would be obvious.
I notice the evaluation board includes a resistor in the gate trace; I've added a 27Ω resistor to my board. The decoupling cap is already ceramic.
Inductor datasheet saturates at 2.8A.
The assembly is behaving itself for now. I will continue to test for several days.
